# Program for dynamically allocating memory (structure based) running differently on different IDEs

Tags: c, struct, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am writing a program to create a structure which is used to create a list, but I am getting a double free or corruption error. I know that linked lists would be a better implementation, but I want to know what I am doing wrong here. The code runs perfectly in my IDE, but shows the 
aforementioned error on running using GCC on Ubuntu's terminal.

```
/* Implements an employee structure having name and company name
and can take new employees, delete last employee and display entire list of employees */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

// defining structure employee
typedef struct emp
{
    char name[20];
    char company[20];
}emp;


int p = 0, size = 0;

void create(emp *);
void del(emp *);
void display(emp *);

int main(void)
{
    emp *buffer = malloc(sizeof(emp));
    if (buffer == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error");
        exit(1);
    }
    int n = 0;
    do
    {
        printf("The options are:\n");
        printf("1. Add employee\n");
        printf("2. Delete employee\n");
        printf("3. Display employee\n");
        printf("4. Exit\n");
        printf("Enter from 1 to 4:");
        scanf("%d",&n);
        if (n == 1)
        {
            create(buffer);
        }
        else if (n == 2)
        {
            del(buffer);
        }
        else if (n == 3)
        {
            display(buffer);
        }
    }while(n != 4);
    free(buffer);
    return 0;
}

void create(emp *buffer)
{
    size++;
    if (p != 0)
    {
        buffer = realloc(buffer, size * sizeof(emp));
        if (buffer == NULL)
        {
            printf("Error");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    printf("Enter:");
    scanf("%s%s", (buffer + size - 1)->name, (buffer + size - 1)->company);
    p++;
}   

void del(emp *buffer)
{
    // deletes only last node
    size--;
    buffer = realloc(buffer, size * sizeof(emp));
    if (buffer == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error");
        exit(1);
    }
}

void display(emp *buffer)
{
    int k = 0;
    for (k = 1; k <= size; k++)
    {
        printf("Name:%s\n",(buffer + k - 1)->name);
        printf("Company:%s\n",(buffer + k - 1)->company);
    }
}
```

UPDATE:
I ran valgrind and am getting the following but not able to understand where exactly I am reallocating incorrectly.

```
 ==3322== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==3322==    at 0x4C2FD5F: realloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==3322==    by 0x4008C9: create (in /home/akshay/Data/practice/a.out)
==3322==    by 0x40081C: main (in /home/akshay/Data/practice/a.out)
==3322==  Address 0x5203040 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 40 free'd
==3322==    at 0x4C2FD5F: realloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==3322==    by 0x4008C9: create (in /home/akshay/Data/practice/a.out)
==3322==    by 0x40081C: main (in /home/akshay/Data/practice/a.out)
==3322==  Block was alloc'd at
==3322==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==3322==    by 0x400786: main (in /home/akshay/Data/practice/a.out)
==3322== 
Error==3322== 
==3322== HEAP SUMMARY:
==3322==     in use at exit: 80 bytes in 1 blocks
==3322==   total heap usage: 5 allocs, 4 frees, 2,288 bytes allocated
==3322== 
==3322== LEAK SUMMARY:
==3322==    definitely lost: 80 bytes in 1 blocks
==3322==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3322==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3322==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3322==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==3322== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
==3322== 
==3322== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==3322== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Comment: Post a [MCVE] or use a debugger/sanitizer.

Comment: Likely a problem with your pointers to `buffer` as arguments... they should probably be pointers to pointers, eg: `void del(emp **buffer)`

Comment: @Toby But, how would I access those pointers to pointers to make changes to the actual data? Also, the error I am getting is double free or corruption. So, it should be related to freeing memory...

Comment: Use [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org) — as of 2017-04-20, there isn't an https connection available — to tell you where the trouble is.

Comment: Your changes to buffer are not reflecting in main.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing buffer to `create` and `del` by value so whatever changes you make to it are not being reflected. So `free` gets old value of `buffer`. You have 3 options -

O1 : make buffer global like you did for size and don't pass it as an argument. Easy but non advised.

O2 : return new value of `buffer` from `del` and `create`. Then while calling do

```
buffer = del(buffer);
```

O3 : Pass a pointer to buffer instead of buffer and modify it inside. Your prototype will change to

```
void create(emp ** buffer);
```

And you will have to use `*buffer` every where inside `create` (same for `del`).
Also the call will change to

```
create(&buffer);
```

This is a bit complicated but the most "correct" one.

Hope that helps you understand the issue.